# FFMPEG Batch Processing

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a ffmpeg command that will happily process all video files in a folder one by one, but how can i make it process them simultaneously?

here's my current command:

``` for i in *.mov; do name=``echo $i | cut -d'.' -f1``; echo $name; TIMECODE=$(ffprobe "$i" -v error -show_entries stream_tags=timecode -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 | awk -F: '{ print $1 "\\:" $2 "\\:" $3 "\\:" $4 }') ; ffmpeg -i "$i" -vf "trim=start_frame=192,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=1280:-1:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/droid/DroidSansMono.ttf: fontsize=28: timecode='00\:00\:00\:00': r=24: x=(w-tw)/2: y=25: fontcolor=white: box=1: boxcolor=0x00000099" -threads 4 -c:v mpeg1video -b:v 5000k -af "atrim=start=8,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS" -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 192k "${name}_mpeg1.mpeg" ```

Answer (score 1):

All that you need is to put an & at the end of the ffmpeg command line. This will make the ffmpeg process to run in background, allowing it to be executed simultaneously with other processes.

```
#!/bin bash
# add this code to a file called encode or whatever you want
# make it executable: chmod ugo+x encode
# and you are ready to run: ./encode

for i in *.mov; do 
    name=``echo $i | cut -d'.' -f1``; 
    echo $name; 
    TIMECODE=$(ffprobe "$i" -v error -show_entries stream_tags=timecode -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 | awk -F: '{ print $1 "\\:" $2 "\\:" $3 "\\:" $4 }') ;
    ffmpeg -i "$i" -vf "trim=start_frame=192,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=1280:-1:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/droid/DroidSansMono.ttf: fontsize=28: timecode='00\:00\:00\:00': r=24: x=(w-tw)/2: y=25: fontcolor=white: box=1: boxcolor=0x00000099" -threads 4 -c:v mpeg1video -b:v 5000k -af "atrim=start=8,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS" -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 192k "${name}_mpeg1.mpeg" &;

    # limit ffmpeg processes to 5
    while [$(ps | grep ffmpeg | wc -l) -eq 5]; do
        echo "ffmpeg queue is full, waiting...";
        # amount of seconds to wait till we check again
        sleep 10;
    done
done;
```

Comment: Will this start a process for each loop member at once? If yes, is there a way to limit the number?

Comment: Yes @Mulvya, added a loop that limits simultaneous ffmpeg processes to 5, you can change that on the -eq 5 to the number that best fit your needs. Important to notice that it will consider any process that has 'ffmpeg' in its name, but that shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

#### Put it into a flexible wrapper script

There's a few benefits to doing it this way, for example, the provided script;

1. Uses `find` and array variables to handle complex and crazy filenames, and the process management
2. Records the process ID's as it spawns `ffmpeg` and then periodically checks them if they are active
3. If a file already exists in it's desired output form (i.e. file_mpeg1.mpeg), that file is skipped; this prevents saying running a loop of 100 files, failing for some reason after 90 files, and then re-running the whole thing from the start.  (there is however no check at this stage to see if the existing file was complete or not.  This goes a bit deeper into error checking / maybe a length compare based on original / an ffprobe, etc... )
4. The flexible template allows you easily manipulate the flow.

I tested it to process 4 random files downloaded off youtube:

[image]

As you can see it handles silly filenames quite well.

Here is the wrapper script based on your commands:

The syntax is: `./scriptname.sh [ext] [maxprocesses]`

- So, to look to look for *.mov files and run 5 processes:

  - If the script name was `script.sh`, then you'd run

    - `./script.sh mov 5`

**Wrapper Script:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

ffprocess () {
    file="$1"
    output="$2" 
    TIMECODE=$(ffprobe "$file" -v error -show_entries stream_tags=timecode -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 | awk -F: '{ print $1 "\\:" $2 "\\:" $3 "\\:" $4 }')
    ffmpeg -i "$file" \
    -vf "trim=start_frame=192,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=1280:-1:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/droid/DroidSansMono.ttf: fontsize=28: timecode='00\:00\:00\:00': r=24: x=(w-tw)/2: y=25: fontcolor=white: box=1: boxcolor=0x00000099" \
    -threads 4 \
    -c:v mpeg1video \
    -b:v 5000k \
    -af "atrim=start=8,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS" \
    -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 192k \
    "${output}"
}

#This function gets called when a process is no longer valid and needs removing from the array

removeps () {
    trtmp=()
    for tmpps in "${ffpsid[@]}"
    do
        [[ $tmpps != "$1" ]] && trtmp+=($tmpps)
    done
    ffpsid=("${trtmp[@]}")
    unset trtmp
    return
}

#Checks to see if each process is still active
checkffpsid () {
    for ffps in "${ffpsid[@]}" 
    do 
    ps -p $ffps > /dev/null || removeps "$ffps"
done

}


if [[ "$#" -lt 2 ]]; then echo -e "Usage: $0 [ext] [maxproc]\ni.e. $0 .mov 5" ; exit ; fi

ext="$1"
maxproc="$2"
find . -maxdepth 1 -iname "*.$ext" > inputlist.txt   # Find files with ext specified
IFS=$'\n' read -rd '' -a filelist <<<"$(cat inputlist.txt)" 
for file in "${filelist[@]}"
    do
    name=$(basename "$file")
    name="${name%.*}"                                  # remove ext for name var
    outname="${name}_mpeg1.mpeg"                       # Set output name
    checkffpsid 
    if [ -f "$outname" ]
        then 
        echo "$outname" already exists, skipping ...
    else
        until [[ "${#ffpsid[@]}" -le "$maxproc" ]]
        do
            checkffpsid
            sleep 5
        done
        ffprocess "$file" "$outname" & ffpsid+=("$!") 
    fi
done
```

---

**Just a couple notes**

1. Your "$TIMECODE" variable never gets used ... This is as per your original script.
2. You're better off letting `ffmpeg` manage its own threads by passing `-threads 0` instead of 4